# no individual listeners for multiple date and time pickers

Tags: android

My app contains start time,date end time,date alarm time,date total i have 3 date pickers and 3 time pickers.It is possible to get date & time by writing listeners for each pickers.This looks like lengthy and hard coding.So, is it possible by implementing those listeners without writing individual listeners (total 6 listeners) to get time and date values into edit texts.

Answer (score 0):

You define `DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() DP =new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener(){//Your implementation}` as a single method then assign this method for each DatePicker to each DatePickerDialog using

```
DatePickerDialog.setonDateSetListener(DP)
```

Same for timePicker

Comment: Check this [link](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-datepicker.html) . In point 6 he defines a  `DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener` named  `mDateSetListener ` and then if you have 3 DatePickers named Date_1, Date_2 & Date_3, you use one line of code per DatePicker which looks like this Date_1.setOnClickListener(mDateSetListener)